# How to access table cells from jquery

Tags: jquery

Ok, I have a table which contains multiple rows. Each row contains some data and a hyperlink. When this link is clicked, I need to open up jquery's dialog form and let the user able to edit the data of the corresponding rows. So when the link is clicked, I need to access the values of the corresponding row cells from jquery.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic structure:

```
$("#tableId a").click(function() {
  var row = $(this).closest("tr");
  ...
  return false;
});
```

Inside that you can then access cells most easily by giving marker classes to your cells and then doing things like:

```
var total = row.children("td.total");
```

assuming a class of `total`.

Answer (score 1):

cletus is right... but if you're just up to editing data cell, might as well use [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html)